# Please explain this circumstance: Scanner in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, java.util.scanner

I created 2 classes: **Quadrangle** and **Point**, **Quadrangle** uses 4 **Points** to create one instance.

In **Points**, I have a **Scanner** to get **inputPoint**, so that I can use these Points to build up a **Quadrangle**

The more detail implementation is provided in the source code below.
The problem is,

1. When I make the Scanner local inside the inputPoint, it requires close right at the end of the method.

   If I close it, the inputPoint in the **inputQuadrangle** method cannot be use continuously to create 4 needed Points. I just think that with each inputPoint called, the scanner was create again and again, and it should work. So, what's wrong here?

   *Error in the code block below.*

   If I don't close it, a weak point exsits in the Point class, but inputPoint in the inputQuadrangle method can be use continuously to create 4 needed Points.
2. But when I make the Scanner static like a field, it doesn't require close, and coming along with that, I can use inputPoint in the inputQuadrangle method without any error or weak point.

So, what did I miss? Please point it out.

---

```
Point class with local scanner
package OOPBaiTap;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {
// Thuoc tinh
private String name;
private double x;
private double y;

// Phuong thuc khoi tao mac dinh
public Point() {
    this("A", 0, 0);
}

// Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan hai so thuc lam tham so
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan mot chuoi va hai so thuc lam tham so
public Point(String name, double x, double y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc khoi toa nhan mot doi tuong cua lop Poin lam tham so
public Point(Point point) {
    this.name = point.getName();
    this.x = point.getX();
    this.y = point.getY();
}

// Cac phuong thuc get, set
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc nhap vao mot diem duoi dang hai so thuc, cach nhau boi dau
// ","
public static Point inputPoint() {
    Point point = null;
    System.out
            .println("Nhap vao tung do va hoanh do, cach nhau mot khoang trang: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] s = input.nextLine().split(" ");
    point = new Point(Double.parseDouble(s[0]), Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
    input.close();
    return point;
}

// Phuong thuc toString()
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s;
    if (this.getName() != null) {
        s = this.getName() + "(" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
    } else {
        s = "(" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
    }
    return s;
}

// Phuong thuc main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Diem khoi tao mac dinh
    Point A = new Point();
    System.out.println(A.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi hai so thuc
    Point B = new Point(2, 5);
    System.out.println(B.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi mot xau va hai so thuc
    Point C = new Point("C", 4, 5);
    System.out.println(C.toString());
    Point D = new Point("D", 3, 2);
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi tham so la mot doi tuong cua lop Point
    Point E = new Point(D);
    System.out.println(E.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Nhap vao tung do va hoanh do cua mot diem, sau do in diem do ra
    // console
    Point F = inputPoint();
    System.out.println(F.toString());
}
}
```

---

---

```
Error code thrown out when trying to input a Quadrangle.
****

 input p1: success 

 input p2: 

 Exception in thread "main" Java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found 

at Java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.Java:1540) 

at OOPBaiTap.Point.inputPoint(Point.Java:68) 

at OOPBaiTap.Quadrangle.inputQuadrangle(Quadrangle.Java:30) 

at OOPBaiTap.Quadrangle.main(Quadrangle.Java:95)
```

---

---

```
Point class with static field scanner
package OOPBaiTap;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {
// Thuoc tinh
private String name;
private double x;
private double y;
private static Scanner input;

// Phuong thuc khoi tao mac dinh
public Point() {
    this("A", 0, 0);
}

// Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan hai so thuc lam tham so
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan mot chuoi va hai so thuc lam tham so
public Point(String name, double x, double y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc khoi toa nhan mot doi tuong cua lop Poin lam tham so
public Point(Point point) {
    this.name = point.getName();
    this.x = point.getX();
    this.y = point.getY();
}

// Cac phuong thuc get, set
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

// Phuong thuc nhap vao mot diem duoi dang hai so thuc, cach nhau boi dau
// ","
public static Point inputPoint() {
    Point point = null;
    System.out
            .println("Nhap vao tung do va hoanh do, cach nhau mot khoang trang: ");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] s = input.nextLine().split(" ");
    point = new Point(Double.parseDouble(s[0]), Double.parseDouble(s[1]));
    return point;
}

// Phuong thuc toString()
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s;
    if (this.getName() != null) {
        s = this.getName() + "(" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
    } else {
        s = "(" + this.getX() + ", " + this.getY() + ")";
    }
    return s;
}

// Phuong thuc main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Diem khoi tao mac dinh
    Point A = new Point();
    System.out.println(A.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi hai so thuc
    Point B = new Point(2, 5);
    System.out.println(B.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi mot xau va hai so thuc
    Point C = new Point("C", 4, 5);
    System.out.println(C.toString());
    Point D = new Point("D", 3, 2);
    System.out.println();
    // Diem khoi tao voi tham so la mot doi tuong cua lop Point
    Point E = new Point(D);
    System.out.println(E.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Nhap vao tung do va hoanh do cua mot diem, sau do in diem do ra
    // console
    Point F = inputPoint();
    System.out.println(F.toString());
}
}
```

---

---

```
Quadrangle class
package OOPBaiTap;

public class Quadrangle {
// Thuoc tinh
private Point p1;
private Point p2;
private Point p3;
private Point p4;

// Phuong thuc khoi tao mac dinh
public Quadrangle() {
    this(new Point("A", 0, 0), new Point("B", 0, 1), new Point("C", 1, 1),
            new Point("D", 1, 0));
}

// Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan 4 doi tuong thuoc lop poin lam tham so
public Quadrangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    this.p3 = p3;
    this.p4 = p4;
}

// Phuong thuc nhap vao mot tu giac 4 diem tu ban phim
public static Quadrangle inputQuadrangle() {
    Quadrangle quadrangle = null;
    System.out.println("Nhap vao diem p1: ");
    Point p1 = Point.inputPoint();
    System.out.println("Nhap vao diem p2: ");
    Point p2 = Point.inputPoint();
    System.out.println("Nhap vao diem p3: ");
    Point p3 = Point.inputPoint();
    System.out.println("Nhap vao diem p4: ");
    Point p4 = Point.inputPoint();
    quadrangle = new Quadrangle(p1, p2, p3, p4);
    return quadrangle;
}

// Cac phuong thuc get set
public Point getP1() {
    return p1;
}

public void setP1(Point p1) {
    this.p1 = p1;
}

public Point getP2() {
    return p2;
}

public void setP2(Point p2) {
    this.p2 = p2;
}

public Point getP3() {
    return p3;
}

public void setP3(Point p3) {
    this.p3 = p3;
}

public Point getP4() {
    return p4;
}

    public void setP4(Point p4) {
    this.p4 = p4;
}

// Phuong thuc toString()
@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = new String(p1.toString() + ", " + p2.toString() + ", "
            + p3.toString() + ", " + p4.toString() + ".");
    return s;
}

// Phuong thuc main()
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Phuong thuc khoi tao mac dinh
    Quadrangle a = new Quadrangle();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Phuong thuc khoi tao nhan 4 doi tuong thuoc lop point lam tham so
    Point p1 = new Point(0, 0);
    Point p2 = new Point(0, 2);
    Point p3 = new Point(2, 1);
    Point p4 = new Point(1, 0);
    Quadrangle b = new Quadrangle(p1, p2, p3, p4);
    System.out.println(b.toString());
    System.out.println();
    // Nhap vao 4 diem cua tu giac tu ban phim
    Quadrangle c = inputQuadrangle();
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: Closing the `java.util.Scanner` (using `input.close()`) also closes the underlying stream `System.in`. Subsequent invocations to `Scanner.nextLine()` cannot read any more lines from the closed `System.in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the documentation for `System.in`

```
The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. 
Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
the host environment or user.
```

So, you need not to worry about closing `System.in` as it there mainly for `debugging`/ `testing` purpose(s) and once closed you should not try to read from it as that will result into exception.

You are getting `NoSuchElementException` exception because `System.in` is `closed` in the previous call to `inputPoint()` and your code is trying to read from it. Also, the error has nothing to do with `static` as you have quoted in the second point. In that case also if you close the scanner instance - you will get the same error.

However, if its a stream that points to some system resource such as a `file` you should close it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. I'm absolutely newbie to Java :)